# Can Common Table expressions be used here for performance?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can COMMON Table expressions be used to avoid having SQL Server perform the following string parsing twice per record? My guess is "no."

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Client_ID
    ,RIGHT('0000000' + RIGHT(Client_ID
                             ,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%'
                                       ,REVERSE('?' + Client_ID)) - 1)
           ,7) AS CorrectedClient
FROM
    membob_vw
WHERE
    Client_ID <> RIGHT('0000000' + RIGHT(Client_ID
                                         ,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%'
                                                   ,REVERSE('?' + Client_ID)) - 1)
                       ,7)
ORDER  BY
    1
    ,2
```

Every time I try to format the SQL as a "Code Block" it looks good (displaying on multiple lines) until the page is refreshed, after which point the SQL is displayed , for me at least, all on ONE line- and I can't seem to corerct that.

Does it display that way for people that are using a browser new that IE6? My company imposes this POS browser on me and prevents me for using any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, a CTE will not do anything performance wise for this query.  It may seem strange/inefficient to type in the same thing large string expression twice.  However, SQL Server will only do the string expression one time per row, it has been optimized for things like that.

**EDIT**
the CTE will reduce the duplicate code:

```
;WITH AllRows AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    Client_ID
    ,RIGHT('0000000' + RIGHT(Client_ID
                             ,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%'
                                       ,REVERSE('?' + Client_ID)) - 1)
           ,7) AS CorrectedClient
FROM
    membob_vw
)
SELECT * FROM AllRows WHERE Client_ID<>CorrectedClient
ORDER  BY
    1
    ,2
```

but won't perform any better.  USE `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` and I'll bet you see the same query plan for each version.

**BE CAREFUL trying to make queries look pretty and reduce redundant code fragments!** simple looking SQL changes can have major adverse performance implications!  always performance (run and/or query plan) check any changes you make.  I have seen trivial changes made to queries that run instantly, that results in them then taking minutes to run.  The key with SQL is performance not pretty code.  If the application is slow, who cares if the code looks good.

Comment: That's what I thought. i was hoping that there was a was to minimize redunadant code like by defining sort of a "row sub routine"

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be running this query a lot, and especially if Client_ID is seldom updated, you should consider a computed column or pre-calculating CorrectedClient and storing it separately.

Comment: +1, the real problem with this query is the way the data is stored.  Whenever you do crazy string manipulations on your data to get a needed value, that is a red flag for a bad design. If a column contains several "parts" that when split apart have individual meanings, you should store them as individual columns.  Example, if you have a column "PersonName" and you store it as "first middle last", everything will be fine until you need to search and/or sort your data by last name. At that point you can use a ridiculous string split routine or create 3 columns: FirstName, MiddleName, LastName.